# Upgradation from infragistics 11 to 13

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, infragistics

I have done an upgrade of infragistics from version 2007 to 2011 successfully by using Version utility available in 2011, but when I did same process for 2011 to 2013 conversion, version utility fails with some popup like I have retired controls, so I have few questions

1. Can't we do it by using version utility like what we have done from 2007 to 11. If not I have to do manual replacement?
2. I was trying to replace manually by installing 2013 infragistics in to a project which is having 2011. When I just imported a webtab which contains ultrawebtab, it is showing like some error which points that it has definition from both 2011 and 2013 versions installed in GAC. What does it mean, whether referring versions from GAC rather then from project BIN is the issue or I have to uninstall 2011 and then start with 2013 which I can't assume the complexity.

**UPDATE**
I have read like we have to mix versionfree dlls of both(i doubt here whether only one so here previous one 2011 or both) inside bin folder ,when i did i am getting overwrite errors.Obviously we cant mix two dll's of same.The link which i followed is [migration to 2013](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/82793.aspx) .I dont the steps they mentioned are correct or not

Comment: Versionfree assemblies not doing trick

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I've been there...

You don't necessarily have to delete 2011. It is not the real issue you are running into. Check the web.config, it sounds most likely you have an assembly for both 2011 and 2013 in it and it doesn't know which one to use. Simply delete the 2011 version.

Also, another thing that has tripped me up in the past is to make sure, in the Visual Studio toolbox, you are using the tools for 2013. If you have a toolbox tab for the 2011 version, unless you are still using it, delete that toolbox tab if it exists, otherwise it will give you a cryptic error about both versions being present when you drag/drop a control on your form.

If you decide to use a different version of .NET, the Infragistics control assemblies will be different, i.e. for .NET 4.5 the assemblies will start with "Infragistics45", but that is another issue to be aware of, if you go down that road.

The errors can be quite frustrating when they don't really tell you what the problem is, but fixing them is usually not that involved.

For deprecated or retired controls, you will have to manually fix. The equivalent new control syntax is usually just different enough that it can be tedious to fix, but I have found to be not too difficult, once you get into it. I would first comment out the offending errors until the Version Utility runs, and then go back and fix them.

As I recall, the 2013 update had a few gotchas that needed fixing, which you are running into. If or when you decide to upgrade further (2014 or 2015) the only control I had any issues with was the WebTextEditor.

Comment: i updated my question , if i have 2011 and migrating to 2013 what is the exact step based on link.rite now i am accessing from GAC

Comment: My suggestion is to comment out the controls that have errors from the version utility. Run version utility (until successful with commenting out controls with errors). Manually drag and drop in the new replacement controls. I have not used the version free controls for the very reason you have run into.